# Easy example of a herbrand structure

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Can someone give me an easy example of a Herbrand structure?

I can't really visualise the difference between a Herbrand and a normal structure.

Comment: See the post [Logic - Satisfaction of a statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138001/logic-satisfaction-of-a-statement).

Comment: I read it but the difference is still not really clear. A structure/Interpretation for me is just a domain (non-empty set) in which we give values to non-logical symbols. ( This can be object symbols, function symbols and predicate symbols ). But I can't understand Herbrand structure intuitively even when I check multiple websites and stackposts.

Comment: It exactly what you said : syntactical objects (like e.g. individual constants) are used also as elements of the domain of the interpretation. Thus, the *term* $c$ is the "name" of the *object* $c$.

Comment: In the linked example, we have a formula that is satisfiable in an interpretation with domain having as elements the *numbers* $0$ and $1$ but it is **not** in the Herbrand structure having the domain with only one object : the constant $c$.

Comment: Can you explain me shortly what a Herbrand structure is? Of course I checked thé définition on wikipedia but I don’t really get it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Example*

Consider the very simple FOL formula : $R(c)$.

The *domain* of the [Herbrand structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Definition) is :

> the set of all *ground terms* [i.e. *closed* terms] of the language.

In the above case, we have only the *individual constant* $c$ as gorund term. Thus, the domain is $H = \{ c \}$.

With it, we define the [Herbrand interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_interpretation) :

> an interpretation in which all constants and function symbols are assigned very simple meanings. Specifically, every constant is interpreted as itself, and every function symbol is interpreted as the function that applies it. The interpretation also defines predicate symbols as denoting a subset of the relevant Herbrand base, effectively specifying which ground atoms are true in the interpretation. This allows the symbols in a set of clauses to be interpreted in a purely syntactic way, separated from any real instantiation.

Again, we have a very simple Herbrand inerpretation $H_S$ :

> $H_S = (H, R^H)$,

where $H$ is the domain defiend above and $R^H$ is the subset of $H$ interpreting the *relation symbol* $R$.

Obviously, $R^H = \{ c \}$.